# Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto., asp net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Quando vou realizar a inserção desses dados na tabela, ocorre esse erro:

> Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto.

Segue código com o construtor:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Inserir ()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Inserir(ProjetoViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    Projeto projeto = new Projeto
    {
        Id_projeto = model.Id_projeto,
        Nome_projeto = model.Nome_projeto,
        Gerencia = model.Gerencia,
        Coordenacao = model.Coordenacao,
        Horas_orcadas = model.Horas_orcadas,
        Impacto = model.Impacto,
        Esforco = model.Esforco,
        Meta = model.Meta,
        Design_sprint = model.Design_sprint,
        Prioridade = model.Prioridade
    };

    _projetoNegocios.Salvar(projeto);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

View:

```
public class ProjetoViewModel
{
    public int Id_projeto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]
    public string Nome_projeto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]
    public string Gerencia { get; set; }


    public string Coordenacao { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]

    public DateTime Horas_orcadas { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]

    public string Impacto { get; set; }

    public string Esforco { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]

    public string Meta { get; set; }


    public string Design_sprint { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Somente números")]
    public string Prioridade { get; set; }


    public ProjetoViewModel(Projeto projeto )
    {
        Id_projeto = projeto.Id_projeto;
        Nome_projeto = projeto.Nome_projeto;
        Gerencia = projeto.Gerencia;
        Coordenacao = projeto.Coordenacao;
        Horas_orcadas = projeto.Horas_orcadas;
        Impacto = projeto.Impacto;
        Esforco = projeto.Esforco;
        Meta = projeto.Meta;
        Design_sprint = projeto.Design_sprint;
        Prioridade = projeto.Prioridade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque também sua View que está fazendo o submit das informações.

Comment: Coloquei Victor :)

Comment: Você consegue entrar no método post para inserir os dados no formulário ou da o erro quando abre a tela?

Comment: O erro ocorre ao compilar ou em tempo de execução?

Comment: Creio que para instanciar um objeto já preenchendo seria. ``` Projeto projeto = new Projeto(){// preenche o objeto aqui }```

Comment: O erro ocorria em tempo de execução. consegui arrumar colocando apenas um construtor vazio: public ProjetoViewModel( )
    {}

Comment: Foi exatamente o que coloquei na resposta :-) Você precisa marcar ela como resposta para sua pergunta não ficar em aberta (como se não tivesse solução).

Answer (score 1):

Adicione um novo construtor padrão na sua classe Model (ProjetoViewModel):

```
public class ProjetoViewModel
{
    // Novo construtor
    public ProjetoViewModel()
    {

    }

    public int Id_projeto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]
    public string Nome_projeto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]
    public string Gerencia { get; set; }


    public string Coordenacao { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]

    public DateTime Horas_orcadas { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]

    public string Impacto { get; set; }

    public string Esforco { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]

    public string Meta { get; set; }


    public string Design_sprint { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "* Campo obrigatório")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Somente números")]
    public string Prioridade { get; set; }


    public ProjetoViewModel(Projeto projeto )
    {
        Id_projeto = projeto.Id_projeto;
        Nome_projeto = projeto.Nome_projeto;
        Gerencia = projeto.Gerencia;
        Coordenacao = projeto.Coordenacao;
        Horas_orcadas = projeto.Horas_orcadas;
        Impacto = projeto.Impacto;
        Esforco = projeto.Esforco;
        Meta = projeto.Meta;
        Design_sprint = projeto.Design_sprint;
        Prioridade = projeto.Prioridade;
    }
}
```

Explicando: Quando o *DefaultModelBinder* precisa instanciar o objeto (ProjetoViewModel) ele usa internamente o método *Activator.CreateInstance()*, este método confia que o objeto tenha um construtor sem parâmetros.

Como a sua classe *Model* (ProjetoViewModel) não tem um construtor padrão sem parâmetros o erro ocorre.